# Is it possible to manipulate master page content (Remove certain code programmatically )in share point 2013 using csom

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to remove a piece of code from sharepoint master page from a lot of sites,so is it possible to manipulate the master page content using csom.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, get the master page from Master Page Gallery using CSOM, modify the file and replace some content in the file, then set master page using this:

```
web.CustomMasterUrl = masterUrl;
```

Articles:

[Set Custom Master Page through CSOM SharePoint](https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/set-custom-master-page-through-csom-sharepoint/)

[C# Search/Replace in Files](http://www.csharp411.com/searchreplace-in-files/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            var rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
            clientContext.Load(rootWeb);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string CustomMasterPage = rootWeb.CustomMasterUrl;

            var masterPagefile = rootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(CustomMasterPage);

            var stream = masterPagefile.OpenBinaryStream();
            clientContext.Load(masterPagefile);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            if (masterPagefile.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
            {

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream.Value, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    masterPageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                masterPagefile.CheckOut();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var catalog = clientContext.Site.GetCatalog((int)ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
                var files = catalog.RootFolder.Files;
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                fileCreationInformation.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(masterPageContent);
                fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
                fileCreationInformation.Url = rootWeb.CustomMasterUrl;

                files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                masterPagefile.CheckIn(" Test", CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```